# How do I get completion handler to return the data from firebase realtime database?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a function that reads the data from my firebase realtime database and uses  a dispatch group to make sure the data is returned correctly. However i think im missing something as im getting errors and cannot access the value. My function is supposed to check if the user is in my database and return true/false accordingly.

My function:

```
//Checks if the userID given is already an entry in the databse (user has already signed up)
func isIdUsed(ID: String, completion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void){
    
    var userDictionary: NSDictionary = NSDictionary()
    var inDatabase = false
    
    let group = DispatchGroup()
    let ID = getUUID()
    group.enter()
    ref.child("TotalUsers").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary

        userDictionary = value! as NSDictionary
        if totalUsersCheck(totalUsers: userDictionary, ID: ID) {
            inDatabase = true

        }
        //completion(inDatabase)
        group.leave()
          // ...
    }) { error in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        
    }
    group.notify(queue: .main) {
        completion(inDatabase)
        testing = completion
    }
    
}
```

then this is how im trying to extract the variable inDatabase in my view. This is an action of a button.

```
Button(action: {
                            isIdUsed(ID: getUUID(), completion: idUsed){(result) in
                                let databaseResult = result
                            }
                           
                            
                            
                           
                        }, label: {
                            
                            Image(systemName: "arrow.right")
                                .font(.system(size: 24, weight: .bold))
                            //.foregroundColor(.white)
                                .padding()
                                .clipShape(Circle())
                        })
```

This gives me an error and says extra trailing closure passed in call for the isIdUsed function.

and heres the idUsed function:

```
func idUsed(used: Bool) {
        self.uuidUsed = used
    }
```

this is located in my view also.

I have tried printing the result of isIdUsed and i was unsure what to expect but i got a () as a result which i wasnt expecting. THis makes me thing the value of my isIdUsed function is incorrect

Comment: Just delete the trailing closure since you are passing a function as argument, you can’t have both

Comment: Instead of stating how to fix this specific issue - it may be better to provide a simpler solution - a good solution though will be dependent on your Firebase structure. How are you storing the users in the database? Is the key to each node the users uid? Can you include a snippet please? To get your Firebase structure, use the Firebase console->Export JSON and copy and paste a snippet into the question. Oh, it's usually better to leave DataSnapshots as DataSnapshots instead of casting to NSDictionary(). Much easier to work with.